# Apache Maven disappears after installation

Tags: maven, variables

I'm currently trying to study Apache Maven and use it. Everything works without any problems. However, I've bumped into a weird problem connected with Maven on Linux. I use Linux Mint 14 KDE as my development base. Whenever I set up the PATH variable for Maven and the M2_HOME env variable, it works, but both the settings in those variables for Maven disappear after restarting my computer, which is really disturbing as I have to set them again.

I use Maven 3.1.1.

What is the cause of such problems? Variables are set until the moment of restarting the computer.

Comment: What exactly do you do to set the variables?

Comment: for the M2_HOME variable I'm setting the absolute path to my Maven directory. It's: /home/mentor/java/apache-maven-3.1.1/
For the PATH I'm setting the path to the Maven's bin dir:
/home/mentor/java/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/

btw I'm using this tutorial to study Maven:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al7bRZzz4oU

Comment: Most probably, you set this variable for the time of your user session. You need to add it to `/etc/profile`, for example.

Comment: Ok. So do I have to move the entire Maven directory to the /etc/profile.d/ directory to make it work?

Comment: No, you have to add `export M2_HOME=...` and `export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin` to `/etc/profile` file.

Comment: Ok. Everything's working now. Thanks Andrew! ;)